# Is $d \langle X,Y \rangle = \langle dX,dY \rangle$ where X,Y are continous semi-martingales

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Is $d \langle X,Y \rangle = \langle dX,dY \rangle$.

I think the answer is yes because $ d \langle X,Y \rangle=\langle X,Y \rangle_t- \langle X,Y \rangle_s$
and $\langle dX,dY \rangle=\langle X_t-X_s,Y_t-Y_s \rangle= \langle X,Y \rangle_t- \langle X,Y \rangle_s$ after some basic computations. 
Am I correct?. 
Edit(IN response to Saz's comment )
In my stochastic analysis prof's terminology

$dX =\big( X_t-X_s\big)_{0\leq s \leq t}$ i.e it is the increment process of X
Similarly we have

$dY =\big( Y_t-Y_s\big)_{0\leq s \leq t}$ i.e it is the increment process of Y and similarly we have for the quadratic covariation process

$ d \langle X,Y \rangle=\big(\langle X,Y \rangle_t- \langle X,Y \rangle_s \big)_{0 \leq s \leq t}$ i.e it is the increment process of $\langle X,Y \rangle$

So we have that 
$\langle dX,dY \rangle=\langle ( Y_t-Y_s)_{0\leq s \leq t} ( X_t-X_s)_{0\leq s \leq t} \rangle$ and then from the bilinearity of the quadratic variation I get that they are the same.
I think I am a bit confused now .Can you help?

Comment: Could you elaborate why $$d \langle X,Y \rangle = \langle X,Y \rangle_t - \langle X,Y \rangle_s$$....? What are $s$ and $t$ ...?

Comment: @saz i think i dont understand it well enough, our prof said that $d \langle X,Y \rangle= \big( \langle X,Y \rangle_t -  \langle X,Y \rangle_s \big)_{0 \leq s \leq t}$ which is the increment process of the quadratic variation and called it stenographic notation, I see that in various proofs he uses the result which I claimed and attempted to proof. I edited the answer, but its still incomplete. Could you have a look at it? Thanks